# Unable to update ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS from 10.2.5 to 100.1.1

Tags: cocoapods, ios11, arcgis, macos-high-sierra, arcgis-server

I'm using ESRI maps in my application, currently due to some features we are sticking the cocoa pods version to 0.39.0. Now i'm trying to update ArcGIS runtime sdk version to 100.1.1 from my earlier version which is 10.2.5. So i have made the modifications in my pod file which pointing to v 100.1.1 and when i run pod install, i'm getting the below error.

Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS (~> 100.1.1)` required by `Podfile`
- `ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS (~> 100.1.1)` required by `Podfile`
- `ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS (~> 100.1.1)` required by `Podfile`
- `ArcGIS-Runtime-SDK-iOS (~> 100.1.1)` required by `Podfile`

[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

My question is the latest v 100.1.1 compatible with cocoa pods v 0.39.0? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the suggestions I posted to your identical question at the Esri Community:

https://community.esri.com/thread/205945-unable-to-update-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-ios-from-1025-to-10011

Best to keep the conversation in one place. This time I spotted that one first :)

(Also, this isn't arcgis-server - it should be tagged arcgis-runtime)